# How does "sort" in shell compare two lines?

Tags: shell, sorting

The experiment is under Ubuntu14.04 and Ubuntu12.04

A normal ASCII file named words.txt:

```
a a
aachen Aachen
zyuganov Zyuganov
z z
```

When I use

```
sort -k 1,1 words.txt
```

The result is

```
a a
aachen Aachen
z z
zyuganov Zyuganov
```

It makes sense for me.

But for command

```
sort words.txt
```

The result is

```
a a
aachen Aachen
zyuganov Zyuganov
z z
```

The result shows: 
"a" or "a " < "aachen"

and"z" or "z " > "zyuganov"

Another strange case in my test is that "zz" is smaller than "zZ".

I can't guess what rules make such result?

Comment: Are you sure `sort file` produces the last output?  Sort compares the full line and since space comes before any letter `z z` should appear before the `zyu..` line.  Even if you use a locale it should be consistent.  You can try the `--debug` option to give you more details.

Comment: @karakfa, what OS are you using? For me, GNU sort in OSX is version 5.93, which does not include a `--debug` option. I have an Ubuntu box with GNU sort version 7.4 that also doesn't include it.

Comment: Ah, found it -- modern FreeBSD's non-GNU sort includes `--debug`. Interesting output, thanks for the tip - I didn't know that existed in FreeBSD. :)  Oh, and I can't reproduce the OP's results in any of these.

Comment: `$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21`

Comment: Basically, the default sort largely ignores blanks etc, so `zz` comes after `zy`.  It's a nuisance.  You can set `LANG=C` or `LC_ALL=C` and see if the sort behaviour changes (it probably will).  Is your default locale setting `en_US.UTF_8` or something similar?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Here is my debug info:  "sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules".  In my computer that "z z" is smaller "z Z" which does't accord with your explanation.

Comment: have you even tested `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Though after "export LC_ALL=C" it works, I don't think it's a prerequisite to sort. Without it sort can't work properly?

Comment: Define "properly". I my native language the proper order of "letters" is: `a á b c cs d ...`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How do you get the order of "letters"? I think it's a key to solving such problems. Knowing the order of  letters in OS used, I can predict the result of sort.

Comment: http://teaching.idallen.com/net2003/06w/notes/character_sets.txt

Comment: BTW, the collation of unicode in itself is sheer madness... http://www.unicode.org/charts/uca/ and http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks a lot